# Nginx: What's the difference between "adding" https and redirecting http to https?

Tags: nginx, https

I have two server blocks. Both do a similar thing: Allowing me to use https.

Now I just wonder, in one case I redirect all traffic from http to https. In the other it just seems as though I am allowing https.

Can somebody explain to me, what the difference is? Since when I am requesting my domain, even with **http**://test.example.com, I still get in both cases a redirect to https.

Is there any difference at all?

These are the two files:

### File 1- Redirecting http to https

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name test.example.com
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /var/www/test/staging/current;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name test.example.com;

    include snippets/ssl-test.example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

### File 2 - Adding https

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /var/www/test/staging/current;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name test.example.com;
    include snippets/ssl-test.example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the details in your question, File 2 appears to accept connections over both `http` and `https` without redirection from one to the other.

However:

- your application may force connections to be in `https`, causing a redirect if `http` is detected, or
- your `ssl-params.conf` file may contain a *Strict Transport Security* header that causes your browser to force the connection to be `https`

Comment: Thanks. I had this line `add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";`in my `ssl-params.conf` like you said.

Answer (score 1):

The second config should not redirect. When you tested the first config before, your browser might have cached the redirect (a cache, which is hard to remove, try another browser(profile)).

And you can still use the second config with redirect, when you match for `$scheme = http` and then redirect. This can simplify your config.